# Imagick pixel iterator - very slow

Tags: php, performance, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to implement [this code snippet](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#109809) (a "vignette" effect) with Imagick, but the processing is incredibly slow:

```
set_time_limit(90);
$iterator = $imagick->getPixelIterator();
$width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
$height = $imagick->getImageHeight();

foreach($iterator as $y => $pixels){
  foreach($pixels as $x => $pixel){

    $l = 1 - 0.7 * (1 - pow((sin(M_PI / $width * $x) * sin(M_PI / $height * $y)), 0.4));       

    extract($pixel->getColor());   

    $pixel->setColor(sprintf('rgb(%d,%d,%d)', $r * $l, $g * $l, $b * $l));
  }

  $iterator->syncIterator();
}
```

Original:

[image]

Result:

[image]

For a 1600x1200 image, it takes like 35 seconds for image to be processed. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 35 seconds for 1,920,000 operations that involve pow, sin, get and setColor, I think Imagick is doing fine.

Comment: but with GD the same effect is applied faster with imagesetpixel, like 12 secs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is over kill ImageMagic already has `-vignette` command

```
convert input.jpg -background black -vignette 70x80 output.png
```

**Original**

[image]

**Final Output**

[image]

Comment: but is this possible using PHP functions? I tried vignetteImage() but it turns the image into a ellipse with white background :)

Comment: see : http://eclecticdjs.com/mike/tutorials/php/imagemagick/examples_04/vignette.php

Comment: @Baba link is now dead.